# Refresh parent window after iframe fancybox closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, fancybox

I have a site that when I click on a link it pops open a fancybox window for a user to enter some details in to the form.

Once the user has finished with the form and closes it I want the parent window to refresh so the new data shows.

I am using fancybox version 2.1.5 and would prefer if I can make the change to jquery.fancybox.js to implement this change and not on the individual boxes as this is something that needs to work on all fancy boxes.

Any suggestions?

This is how I am running the fancybox at the moment:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.fancybox').fancybox();

        $("#fancybox-manual-b").click(function() {
            $.fancybox.open({
                href : 'device-info.php',
                type : 'iframe',
                padding : 5
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

This is referenced from the href like  this:

```
<a class="fancybox fancybox.iframe" href="edit-device.php"><img src="img/edit.png"</a>
```

Comment: The better way seems to be using `afterClose` callback, explained [here](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). Can you provide the code that calls fancybox? It's **strongly** recomended not changing jquery.fancybox.js code, so it's probably better adapting the fancybox calls.

Comment: I have edited it as requested to have the code. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a general config object and just modify the needed attribute per call. Something like this:

```
// This is the basic config, common to all calls
var fancybox_general_config = {
    type : 'iframe',
    padding : 5,
    afterClose: function() {
        location.reload();
    }
}

// modifies just the href attribute, keeping other values
fancybox_general_config.href = 'device-info.php';
$("#fancybox-manual-b").fancybox(fancybox_general_config);

// modifies just the href attribute again, keeping other values
fancybox_general_config.href = 'device-info-2.php';
$("#fancybox-manual-c").fancybox(fancybox_general_config);
```

Hope it helps!